# Reading a two-column file into Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a data file called "test.dat" which is of the form "1 2 \n 3 4 \n 5 6".

If I run the following code, I get two arrays with the numbers in them:

```
import csv
from numpy           import *
f2 = open('test.dat', 'r') 
lines = f2.readlines()
x = []
y = [] 
for line in lines:
    p = line.split()
    x.append(float(p[0]))
    y.append(float(p[1]))
f2.close() 

print x
print y
```

However, I tried writing a function of the form

```
def Read_Two_Column_File(file_name):
    data  = open(file_name, 'r')
    lines = data.readlines()
    x = []
    y = []
    for line in lines:
        p = line.split()
        x.append(float(p[0]))
        y.append(float(p[1]))
    data.close()
    return x, y

x, y = Read_Two_Column_File('test.dat')

print x 
print y
```

but this only returns the two last numbers. What is going wrong here?

Comment: How many lines does `test.dat` have? It should have 3 with two numbers on each when viewed in an editor. Your code works fine for me.

Comment: Works fine for me too. Try running the whole thing from scratch, i.e. create a new test.dat with the data you posted here and copy the code from your question.

Comment: test.dat does have three lines with two numbers on each. I tried creating a new test2.dat file and a new python file, but it is still not working. That's weird if it is working for you guys.

Comment: If I add more lines with two numbers to the data file, then somehow the loop only picks the last two, it appears.

Comment: Try adding `print p` after the split and see what is displayed.

Comment: I added a print p and a print x,y and it does seem that p gives ['1', '2'] etc for every term in the loop. However, x and y are only printed for the last line..

Comment: I copied the code from the text in my question here and now it works. I guess there was some problem with tabs/indents or something? Really weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your comment it would suggest that you did have mixed `tab` and `space` indenting causing your problem. I could suggest a few minor changes to your code as I could see you were thinking of using the `csv` module:

Version 1 - use `with` to ensure the file is closed automatically

```
def Read_Two_Column_File(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as data:
        x = []
        y = []
        for line in data:
            p = line.split()
            x.append(float(p[0]))
            y.append(float(p[1]))

    return x, y

x, y = Read_Two_Column_File('test.dat')

print x 
print y
```

Version 2 - a possible solution using the `csv` module

```
import csv

def Read_Two_Column_File(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
        x = []
        y = []
        for cols in csv_input:
            x.append(float(cols[0]))
            y.append(float(cols[1]))

    return x, y

x, y = Read_Two_Column_File('test.dat')

print x 
print y
```

Both versions will display:

```
[1.0, 3.0, 5.0]
[2.0, 4.0, 6.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

if your file looks like that

> $ cat test.dat
>
> 1 2 \n 3 4 \n 5 6

Then your \n is not a true \n, so the readlines() function return the whole line '1 2 \n 3 4 \n 5 6'

Your file must look like that:

> $ cat test.dat
>
> 1 2
>
> 3 4
>
> 5 6

And then your code is correct and it does work.

Comment: That does not explain why the last two numbers are displayed. In your first example it would display the first two numbers.

Comment: @vianney I have a file which looks like your second example. I only used the notation "\n" in the post.